# EF Core Oracle NVARCHAR2 - Can't save cyrillic to db

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core, cyrillic

When trying to keep the Cyrillic alphabet in the database, only inverted question marks are saved in the database.

The model looks like this

```cs
public class Roles {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Appname { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Creating a context like this

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Roles>(entity =>
{
                entity.HasKey(e => new { e.Name, e.Appname });

                entity.ToTable("ROLES");

                entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Name, e.Appname })
                    .HasName("PK_ROLES")
                    .IsUnique();

                entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                    .HasColumnName("NAME")
                    .HasMaxLength(100)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.Appname)
                    .HasColumnName("APPNAME")
                    .HasMaxLength(20)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.Description)
                    .HasColumnName("DESCRIPTION")
                    //.HasMaxLength(256)
                    //.IsUnicode(true);
                    .HasColumnType("NVARCHAR2(256)");
});
```

*Tried and what is commented out and the next line*

[The table looks created correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCLvT.png)

And the execution of this code

```cs
using (var context = new FrontContext())
{
    var roles = context.Roles.ToList();
    var role = new Roles{ 
               Name        = $"ADMINS{DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss")}", 
               Appname     = "TESTAPP", 
               Description = "тестовая роль"};
    context.Add(role);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

[...gives such a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZwvU.png)

Comment: The screenshot (from SSMS I guess) might be lying. Have you tried reading it back (`var roles = new FrontContext().Roles.ToList();`) and examining the result in VS locals/watch window?

Comment: Yes, reading the data saved through the EF also returns inverted questions. The data saved in the database using Toad is read correctly.

Comment: Just noticed `oracle` tag. The code works just fine with SqlServer, so it might be a (typical for Oracle) provider bug. Especially it it is beta version. You'd better check for update or … well, basically there is nothing more you can do since they do not provide support afaik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [thread:4291600@Oracle](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4291600), they fixed it.

Just update Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore to 2.19.80 then you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.IsUnicode(false);`

Ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.propertybuilder-1.isunicode?view=efcore-5.0